# How to get curve's bezier points‘s Global position with python?

Tags: python, bezier-curves

When I'm in curve's *Edit Mode*, I can select curve's points, and I can see its global position in item's Transform. How can I get the global position with python?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the bezier curve object and then run the script which outputs all the curve points in local space and world space.

```
import bpy

o = bpy.context.object
m = o.matrix_world

for s in o.data.splines:
    for p in s.bezier_points:
        print("point in local space:", p.co)
        print("point in world space:", m @ p.co)
```

Comment: thank you very much!!

Comment: sure np! can you please mark the checkmark on the left side of my answer (it becomes green after clicking) if your issue is resolved?

Comment: on more question, if i have the point's global position ,how can change it to local position?

Comment: instead of multiplying by the matrix_world you can multiply by matrix_local to some global points to get their equivalent in local space coords.